# How to get access multiple resource files with the same name?

Tags: java, classpath

Suppose I have two packages p1 & p2 with resource named `abc.properties`: `com.example.p1\abc.properties` and `com.example.p2\abc.properties`.

After the program compiled I can only access to `com.example.p1\abc.properties` using `getClass().getResource(“abc.properties”)`, because of classpath order.

Is there any way to get access to another file (`com.example.p2\abc.properties`)?

**UPD:** I found packaged jar structure the following:

   `p1-1.0.jar:
      com.example.p1
      META-INF
      abc.properties
   p2-1.0.jar:
      com.example.p2
      META-INF
      abc.properties`

So, in fact, code like this `getClass().getResource(“/com/example/p1/abc.properties”)` didn't worked for me

Comment: This has nothing to do with classpath order, since the qualified names aren't actually the same. If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`getResource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-), you'd learn how the qualified name of the resource to be loaded is constructed, and then realize why you only get the one resource.

Answer (score 2):

By default, resources are resolved relative to the `Class` instance being used - so if your class is in the package `com.example.p1` and you use `getClass().getResource("abc.properties")`, you will end up with `com/example/p1/abc.properties`.

To fix this, you can use absolute paths to resolve resources - e.g. `getClass().getResource("/com/example/p1/abc.properties")` or `getClass().getResource("/com/example/p2/abc.properties")`. Note that you need to precede the path with a forward slash and replace any periods in the path with a slash.

Comment: "you will end up with `com/example/p1/abc.properties`", not `com.example.p1/abc.properties`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't worked for me, I've updated my question